# PHP not working on CentOS

Tags: php, wordpress, centos

I copied a wordpress installation into my html-folder on my server `var/www/html`, but it does not show up in my browser afterwards, instead it shows a apache test-page which is located in `var/www/error`.

If I copy a file named `index.html` into html-folder, it indeed shows up when I visit my website. To test PHP i have created a `index.php` on `/var/www/html/test/` now once i go to `mydomainname/test/index.php` then it shows only PHP soruce code. Apache and PHP are installed on my CentOS, also restarted apache after that. Can you help?

Comment: When you say "shows only PHP source code", you mean that when you view source, you see the PHP code? If that is the case, Apache is not parsing the page as PHP. Either PHP is not installed or it is not configured or it is not recognized (e.g. you need to use the full php tag, not the short one).

Comment: yes, I only see the php-code.

Comment: Then, it is not parsing PHP. It has nothing to do with Wordpress or copying code from one server to another. Make extra certain that PHP is installed (I use package PHP53 on CentOS). Reboot the server to make extra certain that Apache restarted. Edit the files in /etc/httpd to make sure php is listed as AddHandler php5-script .php .php5. Make extra certain that you are using the proper <?php tag and not just <?.

Comment: I tried to reinstall PHP and noted some Missing Dependancies, like `Missing Dependency: php-cli = 5.1.6-45.el5_11 is needed by package php-5.1.6-45.el5_11.i386 (updates).` Could this be the cause?

Comment: Yes. I would begin by removing any PHP package installed and then running "yum clean all" and then running "yum install php53". If php53 is not available (for some reason), run "yum install php". If you have a php-httpd package, install that as well (and ask why you have such a nonstandard repository).

Comment: Thank you, done. But now my website shows following message: "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress." But MySQL is installed, I am clueless now...

Comment: Anyway, solved it with `yum install php53-mysql`. Thank you kainaw